# Set the width of bottom sheet in Angular Material 2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Can i set the width of bottomsheet in Angular Material 2 (fixed or in percentage) ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please post some code as well

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `panelClass` config parameter. For example:

In `styles.css`: (The global styles file and not the `component.css` file)

```
.custom-width {
    width: 450px;
}
```

`In your component.ts`:

```
this.bottomSheet.open(BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet, {
  panelClass: 'custom-width'
});
```

https://stackblitz.com/angular/qvokqxjgbrn

**Note:** Only width in pixels will work.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Actually i can define the css class only in styles.scss. Is there a way to define the css class in the scss of component?

Comment: @blacksword Since the bottom sheet's HTML is not part of the component's HTML (it's attached to the document's body), styling won't work in your component. (However, you can try setting an encapsulation of `ViewEncapsulation.None`)

Comment: @Tabrez Ahmed there is some point that the width that I defined is not helping.
Is there any way to define 100% width size?

Comment: @Ezri Y, you can set width: 100vw;

Comment: You saved my day. I was overriding the bottomsheet css and got into trouble when a requirement came for bottomsheet with different widths. This was the answer I was looking for. Thanks for mentioning specifically that you need to add the styles in Style.css.

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to have a full-width bottom sheet like me you can use [@Tabrez Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1184247/tabrez-ahmed) answer and use 100vw instead.

*styles.css / styles.scss*

```css
.full-width {
  min-width: 100vw !important;
}
```

*component.ts*

```js
openBottomSheet(): void {
  this._bottomSheet.open(
    ContactBottomSheet,
    {
      panelClass: 'full-width'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular Material automatically adds **"mat-bottom-sheet-container"** class at load time.

You can change width of bottom sheet by below way

Define Min and Max Width you want to change in styles.css: (The global styles file and not the component.css file)

```
.mat-bottom-sheet-container {
  min-width: 384px;
  max-width: calc(100vw - 128px)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is passible to add a calss for every single bottom sheet via the MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DEFAULT_OPTIONS. That way, it doesn't have to add the calss for every single instance of the bottom sheet. This solution is works with Angular 8.

1. add to app.modules:

```
import {MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DEFAULT_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';

providers: {
  ...
  { provide: MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {panelClass: 'bottom-sheet'} }
}
```

That way the .bottom-sheet class is going to added to the all mat-bottom-sheet-container. You jast have to add the width for the class in css.

Check more options in the documemation:
https://material.angular.io/components/bottom-sheet/overview